# Android java share on twitter - not founding the twitter app

Tags: java, android, twitter

On my android app, I want to share videos on twitter, for that I have the following code:

```
btnShareTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            videoMoreLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoActions = new VideoActions();
            final String id = videoIDs[position];

            if (!isOnline()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        activity.getString(R.string.noInternetConnection),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                String finalVideoName = null;
                String arr[] = videoPathURL[position].split("/upload/videos/");
                finalVideoName = (arr[arr.length-1]);

                File DoutFile = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                        File.separator + "vidytape_shared" + File.separator + finalVideoName);

                Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                tweetIntent.setType("video/*");
                tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(DoutFile));
                tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

                /*Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        videoPathURL[position]);
                tweetIntent.setType("video/*");*/

                PackageManager packManager = activity.getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager
                        .queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, 0);

                boolean resolved = false;
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
                    if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.name.equals("com.twitter.android.PostActivity")) {
                        ActivityInfo actInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
                        ComponentName cName = new ComponentName(actInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, actInfo.name);
                        tweetIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        tweetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                        tweetIntent.setComponent(cName);
                        resolved = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (resolved) {
                    if(!DoutFile.exists()){

                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Preparing video. Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        String downloadResult = videoActions.downloadToShare(token, activity, id, videoPathURL[position], finalVideoName);
                        if (downloadResult.equalsIgnoreCase("POST_FAILURE") || downloadResult.equalsIgnoreCase("FAILURE_102")) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    activity,
                                    activity.getString(R.string.someErrorOccurred),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }                           
                    }
                    activity.startActivity(tweetIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity,
                            activity.getString(R.string.twitterNotInstalled),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

But I'm getting the Toast message that twitter is not installed... I'm with android 4.4.2, I don't know if it can have something to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try using com.twitter.applib.composer.TextFirstComposerActivity instead of com.twitter.android.PostActivity .. Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952420/twitter-postactivity-issue for more information

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do not use edit on your question to post your answer, please use the answer form below.